# WebBrowser em C# utilizando Chrome

Tags: c#, winforms, google-chrome

Eu tenho uma aplicação de navegador que criei utilizando a classe `WebBrowser` do `System.Windows.Forms`, esta classe utiliza o motor do navegador IE.

Agora eu preciso criar uma aplicação de navegador utilizando o chrome.
Qual a melhor biblioteca para que eu faça isto?
Estou pesquisando CefSharp. Procede?

Comment: Sim, considerando que você está usando Windows Forms, [este pacote pode ser o ideal](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.WinForms/). [As instruções de como usar estão aqui](https://github.com/cefsharp/cefsharp/wiki). [Há um exemplo de uso aqui](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/master/CefSharp.WinForms.Example).

Comment: Ok, é que recebi uma informação, não sei se oficial, de que ela usa o webkit e o webkit teria sido descontinuado. Procede?

Comment: [Aqui diz que você pode trocar o motor de browser](https://cefsharp.github.io/) pelo Gecko, Awesomium, etc.. Não sei te dizer em detalhes.

Comment: Daria pra fazer isto usando o próprio System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser?

Comment: Trocar o motor do browser? Não.